# What are the differences between an environment node and a image node?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

Are there any differences between the cycles *Environment texture* node and the *Image texture node* besides the available projections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the definitions for the [Image Texture node](http://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/blob/HEAD:/intern/cycles/kernel/shaders/node_image_texture.osl) and for the [Environment Texture node](http://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/blob/HEAD:/intern/cycles/kernel/shaders/node_environment_texture.osl), the only difference I note is the available projections. As you noted, *Environment Texture* offers *Equirectangular* and *Mirror Ball*, whereas *Image Texture* offers *Flat* and *Box*.

Some things both have in common are that both will unpremultiply the alpha data, and both will convert sRGB to scene-linear color space. Other than that (and the complications of the *Box* projection), the files are basically identical.