# Can't use image as world texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, image, world

I want the background of my scene to use a sky texture I have setup the nodes to use a image texture but instead of unseeing the sky texture I added it just looks white. Here is my setup:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try another texture coordinate from **Vector** type. It depends on what kind of sky texture you used. Just use the one that fits it.

Comment: @LeonCheung setting it to normal has fixed it but now the image is sideways

Comment: To control more on this, you have to use Node Editor. Like [this](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=66496). And see the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/More#Mapping).

Answer (score 7):

If you are trying to use the image as a sky/panorama background, you probably want the [*Environment texture*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/Textures#Environment_Texture) node instead of the *Image texture node*.

The environment node will let you use panorama projection types (Mirror Ball and Equirectangular) This is the only difference between the two nodes, see [What are the differences between an environment node and a image node?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/4867/599).

---

However, if you really want to use the *Image node* for the sky/background (e.g. to have an image stuck exactly behind the camera, always in the same orientation), you will need to adjust the coordinates with a *Mapping node*:

[image]

Note that to edit the world nodes, you must ensure the little globe icon in the header is selected.