# Is there any way to put camera inside the sphere?

Tags: objects, camera

I'd like to use the inside of the sphere as the background image.
Is there any way to do that?

[image]

Comment: Could you explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve and how?

Comment: Oh my. I've mistaken. I mean inside the SPHERE. I'd like to use the insides of sphere as space image, so that the objects could be shown like floating around the universe. But I can't see the rendered image.

Comment: Ok, now it's more clear... but I still don't get what the problem is. I see a camera already inside the sphere. Did you unwrap the sphere, assigned a material, etc..?

Comment: Yes. I did unwrap the image, using uv editor. But the rendered image is blackened, though I've assigned a light in the sphere. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Instead of using a sphere you can use the image as texture in the world

Comment: Holy crap. I didn't know that... I should find it more. By the way, the question above has solved. I forgot to set the brightness of the light... Anyway thanks for your help guys!!

Comment: @KevinKim If you have solved the question you can answer it below, in the question box.

Comment: @KevinKim read: https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/world.html?highlight=world and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6881/cant-use-image-as-world-texture

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8923/how-do-you-use-an-image-as-the-world-background/8929#8929

Comment: Thanks everybody. I really appreciate all of your help.
In the end I took the method of following instruction
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4PZelpbFtDA

Answer (score 2):

Try flipping all the normals toward the inside of the sphere. Then what ever space scene you map to it can be seen from inside it.