# HDR not rendering properly

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I'm doing just a basic setup using an environment node with an hdr file and a object but when I render its still in the panoramic view and it seems the background isn't rendering aswell what can be the issue.
 [image]

Comment: You need to set the projection for the environment texture as equirectangular. See this link: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46517/trouble-viewing-whole-hdr-image-as-cycles-world/46519#46519

Comment: Read also: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6881/cant-use-image-as-world-texture/8978#8978

Answer (score 1):

Disable *Transparent* under the *Film* tab.

[image]