# World Background Image: Environment Texture does not scale right

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, image, world, texture-coordinates

I try to use a background image for the World. I read that **HDR** images are best for that - so I went out and took an HDR image. But I cannot get this image scaled and applied right to my scene, it seems to be *bended and stretched* all over. I would like to **see the whole image** in the background of my object at once.

Tried to apply a Texture Coordinate Node and a Mapping Node and mess with the settings for quite a while now with no success. Even other answers like [this one here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6881/cant-use-image-as-world-texture) did not help. Does it have sth. to do with the format and resolution of my image? Are there other settings I have to adjust?

This the downloadable image I try to use (*HDR 3264 × 2448 jpeg 4:3*) : 
[Outdoor Scene](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2FsEJdefonnWHZ6QWttd05RM2s)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image you are using is *not* an Environment texture, it is a regular High definition photograph. You can't plug such an image into an Environment texture node, as they have their own type of mapping.

My recommended solution is to set it up as a regular image texture with this as your mapping:

[image]

The result is this:

[image]

You can then use the mapping node to adjust how your image fits into the scene.

Comment: thanks a lot! If I may..: If I leave the setting "Repeat" in the Image Texture Node, I cannot scale oder relocate anything in the Map Node, because then repeated parts appear in the camera view, but the settings "Clip" and "Extend" have no effect at all, why is that? And why exactly did you set "Window" in the Texture Coordinate Node? And ... so I can do a bit more research on this topic: What kind of mapping would an HDR image have needed?

Comment: The repeat setting is irrelevant to that happening. That will occur no matter what happens. You need to work around it, as it is a side-effect of the Window input.

Comment: Window sets the image's orientation to your window, so it is always facing you. HDRi's have a very special image derivative of 360 degree images, as they encompass the entire screen in a sphere map.