# How to lock my world background's position? keep following my camera

Tags: shaders, world

I am following this guide to make a world background.

[World Background Image: Environment Texture does not scale right](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91481/world-background-image-environment-texture-does-not-scale-right)

How can I lock the world position?

[image]

Comment: Use _Generated_ texture coordinate instead of _Camera_ or _Window_

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're using *Camera* or *Window* coordinates for your world texture.

Change it to *Generated* (connect the *Generated* output of the Texture Coordinate node to your Image Texture node) to fix it.

(Also make sure you have *Lock Camera To View* unchecked in the N-menu > View tab.)

Comment: Thank you finally make my sun facing the road.

X:90 Y:40 Z:180